# Swing - My class extends JTextPane and calling first my append() and then super.setText() add additional line break

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

Simple enough: I have this SSCCE:

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.text.MutableAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class Test1_ChangeStyleAndAppend extends JFrame {
    public class MyJTextPane extends JTextPane {
        /**
         * Append some text to this pane.
         * @param s
         */
        public void append(String s) {
            try {
               Document doc = this.getDocument();
               doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), s, null);
            } catch(BadLocationException e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Append some text and change line.
         * @param s
         */
        public void appendLine(String s) {
            try {
                Document doc = this.getDocument();
                doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), s + System.lineSeparator(), null);
            } catch(BadLocationException e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
    public Test1_ChangeStyleAndAppend() {
        begin();
    }

    private void begin() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        MyJTextPane pane0 = new MyJTextPane();
        pane0.appendLine("MyJTextPane using append() and then calling setText()");
        pane0.appendLine("Second line. ");
        pane0.appendLine("Third line");
        pane0.setText(pane0.getText() + "At last" + System.lineSeparator());
        pane0.setBorder(new EtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.RAISED));
        add(pane0, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        MyJTextPane pane = new MyJTextPane();
//        changeLineSpacing(pane, 1.5f, false);
        pane.appendLine("MyJTextPane calling appendLine()");
        pane.appendLine("Second line. ");
        pane.appendLine("Third line");
        pane.appendLine("At last");
        pane.setBorder(new EtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.RAISED));
        add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        JTextPane pane2 = new JTextPane();
        pane2.setText("Normal JTextPane calling setText()");
        pane2.setText(pane2.getText() + System.lineSeparator() + "Second line. ");
        pane2.setText(pane2.getText() + System.lineSeparator() + "Third line");
        pane2.setText(pane2.getText() + System.lineSeparator() + "At last");
        pane2.setBorder(new EtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.RAISED));
        add(pane2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * Select all the text of a <code>JTextPane</code> first and then set the line spacing.
     * @param pane the <code>JTextPane</code> to apply the change
     * @param factor the factor of line spacing. For example, <code>1.0f</code>.
     * @param replace whether the new <code>AttributeSet</code> should replace the old set. If set to <code>false</code>, will merge with the old one.
     */
    public static void changeLineSpacing(JTextPane pane, float factor, boolean replace) {
        pane.selectAll();
        MutableAttributeSet set = new SimpleAttributeSet(pane.getParagraphAttributes());
        StyleConstants.setLineSpacing(set, factor);
        pane.setParagraphAttributes(set, replace);
        pane.setCaretPosition(0); //scroll to the top.
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Test1_ChangeStyleAndAppend frame = new Test1_ChangeStyleAndAppend();

            }

        });
    }
}
```

The result is:

[image]

I am with Windows.

I have two TextPanes, one is `JTextPane`, and another is my class extending `JTextPane` and in this one I have defined two convenient methods, `append()` and `appendLine()` in my custom class, but I haven't overwritten super `getText()` method.

Now, when I call `appendLine()` and then call `setText()` in my class, the calling of `getText()` adds another `\r` between lines, making it `\r\r\n` and add additional empty lines between two lines. It's not what I want, I don't want `\r` to be added.

I had this variable of type `JTextArea` and for changing line spacing, I changed it to be `JTextPane` because `JTextArea` cannot have adjustable line spacing. But it occurs all over the project and all the time it used `pane.setText(pane.getText + newText)`. Now I have to search all occurrence of `setText()` and change it to `appendLine()`. Before doing this big change I want to understand why this extra `\r` is added.

If I always call `append()` or always call `setText(pane.getText() + newText)`, it doesn't happen. But if I call `append()` first and then call `setText(pane.getText() + newText)`, `\r` is added.

Someone sheds light on this?

Comment: `I have this SSCCE:` - that is not a SSCCE. MigLayout is not part of the JDK. There is no reason to use a 3rd party layout manager since your question is not about layout managers. Just use a GridLayout.

Comment: Hi, i don't have the reason but if you replace System.lineSeparator() into your appendLine method, you'll obtain the same result into your 1st and 2nd texpane.

Comment: Sorry @camickr I forget about this. I will change it.

Comment: @JulienGauthier thanks, but I don't understand you when you say "Replace System.lineSeparator()` into my method". You wanted to say "get rid of this part"? I add that to save the work of adding new lines every time, that's why it's called `appendLine()`, to distinguish it from `append()`. I use `appendLine()` in the second panel and no additional line breaks are added...

Comment: I have edited the question to use `BorderLayout`. I hope it helps and someone could help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line separator for Windows is "\r\n".

The Document only uses "\n" for the new line string.

Not sure exactly what the problem is but somewhere there is an inconsistency on how the newline string is handled between the insertString(...) and getText() methods.

The simple solution is to update the Document with its newline string, not the platform newline string.

```
//doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), s + System.lineSeparator(), null);
doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), s + "\n", null);
```

Comment: Well you are right, thanks camickr. The reason is unknown but I see this: when calling `pane.getText()` it uses `StringWriter buf = new StringWriter();    write(buf);    txt = buf.toString();`. Here may be where the problem occurs. And if I use this code to get text: `try { string = pane0.getDocument().getText(0, pane0.getDocument().getLength()); } catch (BadLocationException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }` and change `"\n"` back to `System.lineSeperator()`, the problem disappears.

Comment: Bug reported to Oracle and stay await. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: bug reported and archived. Only occurs in Windows. I am with Windows 10.

http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8180276

The previous answer accepted because I have accepted my answers too many times as solution to my question :) Time to show some generosity to others so that we keep on helping each other.

=========================================================================

At last I think the problem appears when I touch the document underneath. I guess, it's because `JTextPane` uses StringWriter to get its content and it's wrong. In JDK 8u111 source code I found:

```
/**
 * Returns the text contained in this <code>TextComponent</code>
 * in terms of the
 * content type of this editor.  If an exception is thrown while
 * attempting to retrieve the text, <code>null</code> will be returned.
 * This is implemented to call <code>JTextComponent.write</code> with
 * a <code>StringWriter</code>.
 *
 * @return the text
 * @see #setText
 */
public String getText() {
    String txt;
    try {
        StringWriter buf = new StringWriter();
        write(buf);
        txt = buf.toString();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        txt = null;
    }
    return txt;
}
```

`StringWriter` may have done something wrong to produce the extra `\r`. Because if I overwrite this method with my method touching the document, problem gone and all output is normal, with `\n` or `System.lineSeperator()`.

```
    /**
     * Override to permit mixed use of append(), appendLine()
     * with setText(getText() + newText). getText() returns
     * inconsistent content with additional blank lines.
     */
    @Override
    public String getText() {
        String s = "";
        try {
            s = this.getDocument().getText(0, this.getDocument().getLength());
        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
            log.error(e);
        }
        return s;
    }
```